# What does Bromantic comedy genre mean?

Tags: comedy, genre, romantic-comedy

I heard that writing a bromantic comedy is the trendy business in many parts of the world including India. But what is Bromantic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromantic_comedy):

> A bromantic comedy is a film genre that is closely related to the romantic comedy film genre with close male relationships instead. Many define it as, "A romantic comedy based on an eerily close platonic heterosexual relationship between two (or more) bros."